# Linq return list of categories in order

Tags: linq, sql-server-2008, hierarchical-data

I tried to search for this on Google/SO but I didn't really know what to search for!

Given:

```
tblCategories
-----------------
ID
Name
ParentID
```

And given say a category ID *n* how would we return it's parent category, and the parent of it's parent etc, until ParentID = 0?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hierarchical queries in LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377413/hierarchical-queries-in-linq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of other questions on this type of issue - try searching for "recursive linq query"  - https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=recursive+linq+query

The general answers are:

- either fetch everything into memory and use something like AsHierarchy in Linq-to-Objects - see http://www.scip.be/index.php?Page=ArticlesNET18#AsHierarchy
- or write a CommonTableExpression in a stored procedure to help - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx